# Почему не могу переопределить массив способом его определения без new?

Tags: c#, массивы

В C# мы можем определить массив четырьмя способами:

```
int[] nums = new int[4] { 1, 2, 3, 5 };
 
int[] nums2 = new int[] { 1, 2, 3, 5 };
 
int[] nums3 = new[] { 1, 2, 3, 5 };
 
int[] nums4 = { 1, 2, 3, 5 };
```

почему я могу переопределить массив с помощью первых трёх способов, например:

```
nums = new int[] {1,2,3};
```

но не могу с помощью 4го способа. Там среда подчёркивает красным и говорит, что ожидает выражение:

```
nums = {1,2}; // ошбика
```

В документации по поводу этого ничего не нашел. IL у всех способов одинаковый. Я считаю, что это из-за "new", мол, не показываем, что хотим выделить новое место под массив. Но что происходит "под капотом"? Почему мы можем так определить массив, но не переопределить?

Comment: [Object and Collection Initializers](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/object-and-collection-initializers). Это синтаксический сахар.

Comment: [Array Initialization](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/arrays/single-dimensional-arrays#array-initialization). В данном случае это [Implicitly Typed Arrays](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/arrays/implicitly-typed-arrays)

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov да, получается, что так, но всё равно непонятно, почему нельзя переопределить так массив. У меня есть только предположение, что так сделали для читаемости, потому что в 4м случае может быть непонятно, что мы делаем с переменной, но это было бы странно, потому что такой синтакис объявления есть только у массивов, и он не перекликается ни с чем

Comment: Потому что так сделали разработчики компилятора. В одном случае реализовали разбор синтаксического сахара, в другом - нет.